# How to make sure that Facebook always gets on the iOS Share Extension list even if Facebook is not installed on the device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8-share-extension

I use iOS Share Extension to share content in my application, but when Facebook is not installed on the device or is turned off, it doesn't get on the list. I would like it to be always on the list, so as my app would send the user to the Facebook page in Safari if the Facebook application is not installed.

Comment: I have the same problem. did you find a solution?